# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{xe^x} \ dx$.

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I know one can solve this in many ways and the answer is $\pi/4$. However I'm interested in one particular solution involving Laplace transform.

I once saw a solution of this integral where one just did something like directly taking the Laplace transform of the integrand and then getting an integral in terms of $s$. So my question is, how does one go from

$$\mathscr{L}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{xe^x} \ dx\right]$$

To some integral like

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^2+1} \ ds = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

I don't remember the steps inbetween or if the first step is even correct but I wan't to know how the Laplace theory was used here. Any one who has a guess?

Comment: Maybe [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839378/laplace-transform-of-ft-t.) is helpful (Laplace transform of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ is $\int_s^\infty F(u)\, du$, where $F=\mathscr{L}(f)$). Your original integral is related to the Laplace transform of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ where $f(t)=\sin{t}$.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you'd be taking the Laplace transform **of** your integral, because that would just be the Laplace transform of a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?
\begin{multline}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{xe^x} dx = \int_0^\infty \sin x \int_1^\infty e^{-sx}dsdx 
= \int_1^\infty\!\!\int_0^\infty\sin(x) e^{-sx}dx\,ds 
\\= \int_1^\infty \mathcal{L}\left[\sin(x)\right](s)ds = \int_1^\infty \frac{ds}{s^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}1 = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{multline}

Comment: Your first step, how did you split the integral like that?

Comment: @Parseval Since $ x^{-1}e^{-x}= \int_1^\infty e^{-sx}ds$, one can be freely substituted for the other, by the substitution property of equality.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}e^{-ax}dx$$ where your integral is $I(1)$. $I'(a)$ is then:
$$I'(a)=-\int_0^\infty \sin(x)e^{-ax}dx$$
which is the Laplace Transform of the sine function. Thus $$I'(a)=-\frac{1}{a^2+1}$$

Integrating back we get:
$$I(a)=-\arctan(a)+C$$ To find the constant, we notice that $$I(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ So we get that $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and that $$I(1)=-\arctan(1)+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that employs the following [useful property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) for the Laplace transform:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L} \{f(x)\} (t) \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{g(x)\} (t) \, dt.$$
Perhaps it is something like this you are looking for?

Noting that
$$\mathcal{L} \{\sin x\}(t) = \frac{1}{1 + t^2},$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \right \} (t)= H(t - 1).$$
Here $H(x)$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Thus

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x e^x} \, dx &= \int_0^\infty \sin x \cdot \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L} \{\sin x\} (t) \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \right \} (t) \, dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{H(t - 1)}{1 + t^2} \, dt.\\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{1 + t^2} \, dt\\
&= \Big{[}\tan^{-1} t \Big{]}_1^\infty\\[1ex]
&= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\\[1ex]
&= \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about this one is even "alternative" approaches accidentally at some point get us a double integral whose further evaluation can be seen as using a result in Laplace transforms. For example, aleden's answer begins exactly the way you would if you said "I'd rather use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)", but look what it gets!

My usual preferred way of solving this sees the same phenomenon. It begins with a [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization), writing $\frac{1}{x}=\int_0^\infty\exp (-sx) ds$. Then the integral becomes $\int_0^\infty ds\int_0^\infty dx\sin x\exp( -(1+s)x)$. Up to a constant variable shift, this yields the deliberately Laplace-based approach in eyeballfrog's answer.